# Android: Fatal Error, SQLite, AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

I've got big problem with fatal error. I need the app be good tomorrow morning so i'm starting to be desperate. I would be grateful for any help!

this is what the error looks like

```
07-14 20:06:38.130 10079-10504/jansoldat.formular100 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=210; index=210
       at jansoldat.formular100.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:254)
       at jansoldat.formular100.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:11)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

This is my BackgroundTask code

```
 package jansoldat.formular100;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Ješek on 16. 6. 2016.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context ctx;
    byte[] byteArray;
    byte[] byteArray1;


    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx,byte[] byteArray,byte[] byteArray1)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.byteArray = byteArray;
        this.byteArray1 = byteArray1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];
        DbOperace dbOperace = new DbOperace(ctx);
        if (method.equals("add_info"))
        {
            String Usek_kom = params[1];
            String Kod_useku = params[2];
            String Kody_soused_poc = params[3];
            String Kody_soused_end = params[4];
            String Soucast = params[5];
            String GPS_pocatek = params[6];
            String GPS_konec = params[7];
            String Mereni_provedl = params[8];
            String Dne = params[9];
            String Delka_kom = params[10];
            String Typ_kom = params[11];
            String Material = params[12];
            String Nerovnosti_Povrchu = params[13];
            String Velikost_Poruch = params[14];
            String Cetnost_Poruch = params[15];
            String Okraj_vlevo = params[16];
            String Okraj_vpraco = params[17];
            String Prostor_vlevo = params[18];
            String Prostor_vpravo = params[19];
            String orient_poc = params[20];
            String Sirka_0m = params[21];
            String Podelny_Sklon_0m = params[22];
            String Pricny_Sklon_0m = params[23];
            String Sirka_2m = params[24];
            String Podelny_Sklon_2m = params[25];
            String Pricny_Sklon_2m = params[26];
            String Sirka_4m = params[27];
            String Podelny_Sklon_4m = params[28];
            String Pricny_Sklon_4m = params[29];
            String Sirka_6m = params[30];
            String Podelny_Sklon_6m = params[31];
            String Pricny_Sklon_6m = params[32];
            String Sirka_8m = params[33];
            String Podelny_Sklon_8m = params[34];
            String Pricny_Sklon_8m = params[35];
            String Sirka_10m = params[36];
            String Podelny_Sklon_10m = params[37];
            String Pricny_Sklon_10m = params[38];
            String Sirka_12m = params[39];
            String Podelny_Sklon_12m = params[40];
            String Pricny_Sklon_12m = params[41];
            String Sirka_14m = params[42];
            String Podelny_Sklon_14m = params[43];
            String Pricny_Sklon_14m = params[44];
            String Sirka_16m = params[45];
            String Podelny_Sklon_16m = params[46];
            String Pricny_Sklon_16m = params[47];
            String Sirka_18m = params[48];
            String Podelny_Sklon_18m = params[49];
            String Pricny_Sklon_18m = params[50];
            String Sirka_20m = params[51];
            String Podelny_Sklon_20m = params[52];
            String Pricny_Sklon_20m = params[53];
            String Sirka_22m = params[54];
            String Podelny_Sklon_22m = params[55];
            String Pricny_Sklon_22m = params[56];
            String Sirka_24m = params[57];
            String Podelny_Sklon_24m = params[58];
            String Pricny_Sklon_24m = params[59];
            String Sirka_26m = params[60];
            String Podelny_Sklon_26m = params[61];
            String Pricny_Sklon_26m = params[62];
            String Sirka_28m = params[63];
            String Podelny_Sklon_28m = params[64];
            String Pricny_Sklon_28m = params[65];
            String Sirka_30m = params[66];
            String Podelny_Sklon_30m = params[67];
            String Pricny_Sklon_30m = params[68];
            String Sirka_32m = params[69];
            String Podelny_Sklon_32m = params[70];
            String Pricny_Sklon_32m = params[71];
            String Sirka_34m = params[72];
            String Podelny_Sklon_34m = params[73];
            String Pricny_Sklon_34m = params[74];
            String Sirka_36m = params[75];
            String Podelny_Sklon_36m = params[76];
            String Pricny_Sklon_36m = params[77];
            String Sirka_38m = params[78];
            String Podelny_Sklon_38m = params[79];
            String Pricny_Sklon_38m = params[80];
            String Sirka_40m = params[81];
            String Podelny_Sklon_40m = params[82];
            String Pricny_Sklon_40m = params[83];
            String Sirka_42m = params[84];
            String Podelny_Sklon_42m = params[85];
            String Pricny_Sklon_42m = params[86];
            String Sirka_44m = params[87];
            String Podelny_Sklon_44m = params[88];
            String Pricny_Sklon_44m = params[89];
            String Sirka_46m = params[90];
            String Podelny_Sklon_46m = params[91];
            String Pricny_Sklon_46m = params[92];
            String Sirka_48m = params[93];
            String Podelny_Sklon_48m = params[94];
            String Pricny_Sklon_48m = params[95];
            String Sirka_50m = params[96];
            String Podelny_Sklon_50m = params[97];
            String Pricny_Sklon_50m = params[98];
            String Sirka_52m = params[99];
            String Podelny_Sklon_52m = params[100];
            String Pricny_Sklon_52m = params[101];
            String Sirka_54m = params[102];
            String Podelny_Sklon_54m = params[103];
            String Pricny_Sklon_54m = params[104];
            String Sirka_56m = params[105];
            String Podelny_Sklon_56m = params[106];
            String Pricny_Sklon_56m = params[107];
            String Sirka_58m = params[108];
            String Podelny_Sklon_58m = params[109];
            String Pricny_Sklon_58m = params[110];
            String Sirka_60m = params[110];
            String Podelny_Sklon_60m = params[112];
            String Pricny_Sklon_60m = params[113];
            String Sirka_62m = params[114];
            String Podelny_Sklon_62m = params[115];
            String Pricny_Sklon_62m = params[116];
            String Sirka_64m = params[117];
            String Podelny_Sklon_64m = params[118];
            String Pricny_Sklon_64m = params[119];
            String Sirka_66m = params[120];
            String Podelny_Sklon_66m = params[121];
            String Pricny_Sklon_66m = params[122];
            String Sirka_68m = params[123];
            String Podelny_Sklon_68m = params[124];
            String Pricny_Sklon_68m = params[125];
            String Sirka_70m = params[126];
            String Podelny_Sklon_70m = params[127];
            String Pricny_Sklon_70m = params[128];
            String Sirka_72m = params[129];
            String Podelny_Sklon_72m = params[130];
            String Pricny_Sklon_72m = params[131];
            String Sirka_74m = params[132];
            String Podelny_Sklon_74m = params[133];
            String Pricny_Sklon_74m = params[134];
            String Sirka_76m = params[135];
            String Podelny_Sklon_76m = params[136];
            String Pricny_Sklon_76m = params[137];
            String Sirka_78m = params[138];
            String Podelny_Sklon_78m = params[139];
            String Pricny_Sklon_78m = params[140];
            String Sirka_80m = params[141];
            String Podelny_Sklon_80m = params[142];
            String Pricny_Sklon_80m = params[143];
            String Sirka_82m = params[144];
            String Podelny_Sklon_82m = params[145];
            String Pricny_Sklon_82m = params[146];
            String Sirka_84m = params[147];
            String Podelny_Sklon_84m = params[148];
            String Pricny_Sklon_84m = params[149];
            String Sirka_86m = params[150];
            String Podelny_Sklon_86m = params[151];
            String Pricny_Sklon_86m = params[152];
            String Sirka_88m = params[153];
            String Podelny_Sklon_88m = params[154];
            String Pricny_Sklon_88m = params[155];
            String Sirka_90m = params[156];
            String Podelny_Sklon_90m = params[157];
            String Pricny_Sklon_90m = params[158];
            String Sirka_92m = params[159];
            String Podelny_Sklon_92m = params[160];
            String Pricny_Sklon_92m = params[161];
            String Sirka_94m = params[162];
            String Podelny_Sklon_94m = params[163];
            String Pricny_Sklon_94m = params[164];
            String Sirka_96m = params[165];
            String Podelny_Sklon_96m = params[166];
            String Pricny_Sklon_96m = params[167];
            String Sirka_98m = params[168];
            String Podelny_Sklon_98m = params[169];
            String Pricny_Sklon_98m = params[170];
            String Sirka_100m = params[171];
            String Podelny_Sklon_100m = params[172];
            String Pricny_Sklon_100m = params[173];
            String Orient_konec = params[174];
            String Staniceni1 = params[173];
            String Parametry = params[173];
            String Staniceni2 = params[174];
            String Parametry2 = params[175];
            String Staniceni3 = params[176];
            String Parametry3 = params[177];
            String Staniceni4 = params[178];
            String Parametry4 = params[179];
            String Staniceni5 = params[180];
            String Parametry5 = params[181];
            String Staniceni6 = params[182];
            String Parametry6 = params[183];
            String Staniceni7 = params[184];
            String Parametry7 = params[185];
            String Staniceni8 = params[186];
            String Parametry8 = params[187];
            String Staniceni9 = params[188];
            String Parametry9 = params[189];
            String Staniceni10 = params[190];
            String Parametry10 = params[191];
            String Staniceni11 = params[192];
            String Parametry11 = params[193];
            String Staniceni12 = params[194];
            String Parametry12 = params[195];
            String Staniceni13 = params[196];
            String Parametry13 = params[197];
            String Staniceni14 = params[198];
            String Parametry14 = params[199];
            String Staniceni15 = params[200];
            String Parametry15 = params[201];
            String Staniceni16 = params[202];
            String Parametry16 = params[203];
            String Staniceni17 = params[204];
            String Parametry17 = params[205];
            String Staniceni18 = params[206];
            String Parametry18 = params[207];
            String Staniceni19 = params[208];
            String Parametry19 = params[209];
            String Staniceni20 = params[210];
            String Parametry20 = params[211];
            String Poznamky = params[212];



            // byte[] ObrazekGalerie = params[7];
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbOperace.getWritableDatabase();
            dbOperace.pridejInformace(db,Usek_kom,Kod_useku,Kody_soused_poc,Kody_soused_end,Soucast,GPS_pocatek,GPS_konec,Mereni_provedl,Dne,Delka_kom,Typ_kom,Material,Nerovnosti_Povrchu,Velikost_Poruch,Cetnost_Poruch
                    ,Okraj_vlevo,Okraj_vpraco,Prostor_vlevo,Prostor_vpravo,orient_poc,Sirka_0m,Podelny_Sklon_0m,Pricny_Sklon_0m,Sirka_2m,Podelny_Sklon_2m,Pricny_Sklon_2m,Sirka_4m,Podelny_Sklon_4m,Pricny_Sklon_4m,
                    Sirka_6m,Podelny_Sklon_6m,Pricny_Sklon_6m, Sirka_8m,Podelny_Sklon_8m,Pricny_Sklon_8m, Sirka_10m,Podelny_Sklon_10m,Pricny_Sklon_10m,Sirka_12m,Podelny_Sklon_12m,Pricny_Sklon_12m,
                    Sirka_14m,Podelny_Sklon_14m,Pricny_Sklon_14m,Sirka_16m,Podelny_Sklon_16m,Pricny_Sklon_16m,Sirka_18m,Podelny_Sklon_18m,Pricny_Sklon_18m,Sirka_20m,Podelny_Sklon_20m,Pricny_Sklon_20m,
                    Sirka_22m,Podelny_Sklon_22m,Pricny_Sklon_22m,Sirka_24m,Podelny_Sklon_24m,Pricny_Sklon_24m,Sirka_26m,Podelny_Sklon_26m,Pricny_Sklon_26m,Sirka_28m,Podelny_Sklon_28m,Pricny_Sklon_28m,
                    Sirka_30m,Podelny_Sklon_30m,Pricny_Sklon_30m,Sirka_32m,Podelny_Sklon_32m,Pricny_Sklon_32m,Sirka_34m,Podelny_Sklon_34m,Pricny_Sklon_34m,Sirka_36m,Podelny_Sklon_36m,Pricny_Sklon_36m,Sirka_38m,Podelny_Sklon_38m,Pricny_Sklon_38m,
                    Sirka_40m,Podelny_Sklon_40m,Pricny_Sklon_40m,Sirka_42m,Podelny_Sklon_42m,Pricny_Sklon_42m,Sirka_44m,Podelny_Sklon_44m,Pricny_Sklon_44m,Sirka_46m,Podelny_Sklon_46m,Pricny_Sklon_46m,Sirka_48m,Podelny_Sklon_48m,Pricny_Sklon_48m,
                    Sirka_50m,Podelny_Sklon_50m,Pricny_Sklon_50m,Sirka_52m,Podelny_Sklon_52m,Pricny_Sklon_52m,Sirka_54m,Podelny_Sklon_54m,Pricny_Sklon_54m,Sirka_56m,Podelny_Sklon_56m,Pricny_Sklon_56m,Sirka_58m,Podelny_Sklon_58m,Pricny_Sklon_58m,
                    Sirka_60m,Podelny_Sklon_60m,Pricny_Sklon_60m,Sirka_62m,Podelny_Sklon_62m,Pricny_Sklon_62m,Sirka_64m,Podelny_Sklon_64m,Pricny_Sklon_64m,Sirka_66m,Podelny_Sklon_66m,Pricny_Sklon_66m,
                    Sirka_68m,Podelny_Sklon_68m,Pricny_Sklon_68m,Sirka_70m,Podelny_Sklon_70m,Pricny_Sklon_70m,Sirka_72m,Podelny_Sklon_72m,Pricny_Sklon_72m,Sirka_74m,Podelny_Sklon_74m,Pricny_Sklon_74m,
                    Sirka_76m,Podelny_Sklon_76m,Pricny_Sklon_76m,Sirka_78m,Podelny_Sklon_78m,Pricny_Sklon_78m,Sirka_80m,Podelny_Sklon_80m,Pricny_Sklon_80m,Sirka_82m,Podelny_Sklon_82m,Pricny_Sklon_82m,
                    Sirka_84m,Podelny_Sklon_84m,Pricny_Sklon_84m,Sirka_86m,Podelny_Sklon_86m,Pricny_Sklon_86m,Sirka_88m,Podelny_Sklon_88m,Pricny_Sklon_88m,Sirka_90m,Podelny_Sklon_90m,Pricny_Sklon_90m,Sirka_92m,Podelny_Sklon_92m,Pricny_Sklon_92m,
                    Sirka_94m,Podelny_Sklon_94m,Pricny_Sklon_94m,Sirka_96m,Podelny_Sklon_96m,Pricny_Sklon_96m,Sirka_98m,Podelny_Sklon_98m,Pricny_Sklon_98m,Sirka_100m,Podelny_Sklon_100m,Pricny_Sklon_100m,Orient_konec,
                    Staniceni1,Parametry,Staniceni2,Parametry2,Staniceni3,Parametry3,Staniceni4,Parametry4,Staniceni5,Parametry5,Staniceni6,Parametry6,Staniceni7,Parametry7,Staniceni8,Parametry8,Staniceni9,Parametry9
                    ,Staniceni10,Parametry10,Staniceni11,Parametry11,Staniceni12,Parametry12,Staniceni13,Parametry13,Staniceni14,Parametry14,Staniceni15,Parametry15,Staniceni16,Parametry16,Staniceni17,Parametry17,Staniceni18,Parametry18
                    ,Staniceni19,Parametry19,Staniceni20,Parametry20,Poznamky,
                    byteArray, byteArray1);
            return "Zápis uložen....";
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Show your `doInBackground` code

Comment: add you're asynctask code!

Comment: This is my code. It's little bit longer so i upload it on my google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B19AM1KNZyS7eVJ3OWczclR4VW8)

Comment: Don't post links to the code, edit your question and add the more relevant parts of your code

Comment: ok,excuse me, i've already edited my question.

Comment: Could you also post the rest of the `AsyncTask` and the code you are using to execute it?

Comment: Your logcat is very clear about the problem. `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=210; index=210`

Comment: Can i upload you the full project? I think that it is really long.

Comment: Yes i know, but sadly don't know how to fix it

Comment: Please read this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you're doing right now is asking us to fix the problem, which isn't how SO works. Besides it doesn't help you learn something from your mistakes.

Comment: Yes i'm sorry, but that is my problem, that i don't know really what to do and actually need to fix it really quick. But i will edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: I tried to fix it, but know I do not really see my mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=210; index=210
```

I quess that you have error in this line:

```
String Staniceni20 = params[210];
```

Simply - paramns[] has 210 and you're trying to get the 211'th

Comment: And do you know please how can i solve it? Because i've got 215 items

Comment: It simply looks like you're missing to pass some parameters, so first place where I would expect bug is AsyncTask.execute(....) method call.

Comment: I've tried to decrease my items so the highest paramns is paramns[209] and it's still not working with the same error the only difference is this
`Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=204; index=204
`

Comment: You just pasted an answer you need. I've no idea what you're doing when passing params, if this set is always this same length etc. Error you pasted is simply saying that you're trying to reach not existing element of array. Just set some breakpoint in your code and check how large is this array.

Comment: Yes you are right I'm sorry. I misunderstood your answer. Now it's working. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

it says your index and length is 210, but in your list in the code you have 212 items, that might have something to do with it. The only other thing I can think of is if you're doing an index the 0 is counted, so try making your index 211 and your length 210?

Comment: Yes you are right i had problem in number of items, but I solve it and it's still showing the same error message